# spaCy doc.ents is inconsistent when running on similar data

Tags: python, spacy

I have a dataframe with a column called "titleFinal". It's the title of a table in a PDF. My current goal is to pull entities from the table titles and then later use them for analysis. I plan on training a model over my data (by creating a list of entities), but so far I've used the base NER. Unfortunately, when I look at what doc.ents extracts, it doesn't seem consistent at all and I'm not sure if I did something wrong or the model is simply extracting entities poorly.

I started with the small model, but there was a noticeable improvement when I switched to the large model. I'm not seeing as many inconsistencies. However, they are still there. For example:

Table 21-9 Cumulative Effects Initial Screening -> [(21)]
Table 21-18 Cumulative Effects Initial Screening – Human Occupancy and Resources -> [(21), (Cumulative, Effects, Initial, Screening, –, Human, Occupancy, and, Resources)]

These inconsistencies happen quite frequently throughout the list of entities so I'm wondering what I can do to resolve this. Is this expected?

Unfortunately, I can't share the dataset yet, but here's the code I'm currently using:

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg") # large model for production

tokens = []
lemma = []
ents = []

for doc in nlp.pipe(df['titleFinal'].astype('unicode').values, batch_size=50,
                        n_threads=3):
    if doc.is_parsed:
        tokens.append([n.text for n in doc])
        lemma.append([n.lemma_ for n in doc])
        ents.append([e for e in doc.ents])
    else:
        # We want to make sure that the lists of parsed results have the
        # same number of entries of the original Dataframe, so add some blanks in case the parse fails
        tokens.append(None)
        lemma.append(None)
        ents.append(None)

df['titleFinal_tokens'] = tokens
df['titleFinal_lemma'] = lemma
df['titleFinal_ents'] = ents
```

Is my approach wrong here?

### Info

- **spaCy version:** 2.2.4
- **Platform:** Linux-4.19.104+-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-18.04-bionic
- **Python version:** 3.6.9
- **Models:** en

Comment: Can you fix the formatting on your output example? I can't really tell what the input and your expected output is. That said, some degree of inconsistency is expected and even desired; for example, in "I ate an apple" and "they work at Apple" only one of those apples is an entity.